# Access Image inside the Button in XAML Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Hi i am New to the XAML i need to change the Image Source that is inside the HyperlinkButton when click on the HyerLinkButton i am firing an event please tell me how to change image source

**Note:** HyperlinkButton Already Inside the ListBox

**XAML**

```
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="SaveData" Width="Auto" CommandParameter="{Binding business_id}" Click="SaveData_Click">
                                        <HyperlinkButton.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Image Source="/Assets/Images/MainPageImg/save.png" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15,0"></Image>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </HyperlinkButton.Template>
                                    </HyperlinkButton>
```

**C# Code**

```
 private void SaveData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton HyperlinkButton = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
        string value = HyperlinkButton.CommandParameter.ToString();
        saveevt = true;
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                db.Insert(new Travel() { id = value });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: try giving a `Name` or `x:Key` attribute to the Image.

Comment: If you override the template of your `HyperlinkButton` with an `Image`, why not using directly an `Image` and listen for the `Tap` event?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SaveData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(
      new Uri("/Assests/Images/MainpageImg/save.png", UriKind.Relative));
image1.Source = null;
image1.Source = imgSource;
```

}

Change the Uri path of image to whatever your new image will be.
Hope this work for you.